# MySQL performance_schema not working properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ubuntu

I have MySQL 5.6.19 community server running on my Ubuntu 14.04. Lately I have been trying to monitor MySQL server using performance_schema. Previously I used to do this by running SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST query every 5 second using a cronjob.

I configured **performance_schema.setup_consumers** table as follows.

```
mysql> use performance_schema;
mysql> select * from setup_consumers;
+--------------------------------+---------+
| NAME                           | ENABLED |
+--------------------------------+---------+
| events_stages_current          | NO      |
| events_stages_history          | NO      |
| events_stages_history_long     | NO      |
| events_statements_current      | YES     |
| events_statements_history      | NO      |
| events_statements_history_long | NO      |
| events_waits_current           | NO      |
| events_waits_history           | NO      |
| events_waits_history_long      | NO      |
| global_instrumentation         | YES     |
| thread_instrumentation         | YES     |
| statements_digest              | YES     |
+--------------------------------+---------+
```

By default the **events_statements_history** is not enabled. I enabled it as follows.

```
mysql> update setup_consumers set enabled="YES" where name="events_statements_history";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from setup_consumers;
+--------------------------------+---------+
| NAME                           | ENABLED |
+--------------------------------+---------+
| events_stages_current          | NO      |
| events_stages_history          | NO      |
| events_stages_history_long     | NO      |
| events_statements_current      | YES     |
| events_statements_history      | YES     |
| events_statements_history_long | NO      |
| events_waits_current           | NO      |
| events_waits_history           | NO      |
| events_waits_history_long      | NO      |
| global_instrumentation         | YES     |
| thread_instrumentation         | YES     |
| statements_digest              | YES     |
+--------------------------------+---------+
```

Now enabled, the **events_statements_history** table should now be able to capture queries but somehow it is not. Following is the result.

```
mysql> select count(sql_text) from events_statements_history;
+-----------------+
| count(sql_text) |
+-----------------+
|               0 |
+-----------------+
```

I do not understand as to why it is not logging in any queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance schema records data when three conditions are met:

1. The running thread is instrumented
2. The instrument currently executed is enabled
3. The consumers for the data to record are enabled

### Threads

By default, every thread (1) is instrumented.

To check if threads are instrumented:

```
select THREAD_ID, NAME, PROCESSLIST_ID, PROCESSLIST_USER, PROCESSLIST_HOST, INSTRUMENTED from threads;
```

To change which threads are instrumented by default, use table setup_actors.

### Instruments

By default, instruments for statements (aka, queries), are enabled (2).

To see which queries are not instrumented:

```
select * from setup_instruments where name like "statement/%" and enabled='NO';
```

To instrument all queries:

```
update setup_instruments set enabled="YES" where name like "statement/%";
```

### Consumers

By default, only a few consumers are instrumented (3).

To see which consumers are instrumented, or to change this, use select / update on table setup_consumers.

This part seems fine per the question, so check part (1) and (2).

Comment: But, what if nothing is in the `setup_%` tables?

Answer (score 1):

As a side-note, if there is nothing inside the `setup_%` tables then you might need to enable the performance schema,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html