# How, using Python, can I find how long a MySQL query took?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm connecting to MySQL with the MySQLdb module. I don't want to use Python's time functions: I want to know how long the query ran within MySQL, i.e. the number I see after I've run a query within MySQL directly.

I do see a thread where this is addressed as something one could eventually dig down to, but I was hoping that since MySQL reports that number, the Python connection would have picked it up somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

May this help?

```
SET profiling = 1;
Run your query;
SHOW PROFILES;
```

See here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html

Ｂｅｃａｕｓｅ　ｏｆ　ｔｈｅ　ａｂｏｖｅ　ｃｏｍｍａｎｄｓ　ｗｉｌｌ　ｂｅ　ｒｅｍｏｖｅｄ　ｉｎ　ｔｈｅ　ｆｕｔｕｒｅ　ｖｅｒｓｉｏｎ，　 Performance Schema ｃａｎ　ｂｅ　ｕｓｅｄ　http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html　ａｎｄ　http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html．

Ｏｎ　ｔｈｅ　ａｂｏｖｅ　ｌｉｎｋｓ，　ｔｈｅｒｅ　ａｒｅ　ｍｏｒｅ　ｄｅｔａｉｌｓ　ｏｎ　Query Profiling Using Performance Schema．

Comment: This returned nothing but a warning that the command was deprecated and would be removed in a later release: but I haven't yet tried the replacement specified by following your link.

Comment: @thelma, what is your mysql version? I　ｃａｎｎｏｔ　ａｃｃｅｓｓ　ｍｙｓｑｌ　ｄｂ　ｎｏｗ．　ｓｏ　Ｉ　ｃａｎ　ｎｏｔ　ｔｒｙ．Ｂｕｔ　ｏｎ　ｔｈｅ　ｄｏｃｕｍｅｎｔ，　ｐｅｒｆｏｒｍａｎｃｅ　ｃａｎ　ｂｅ　ｑｕｅｒｉｅｄ　ｂｙ　ｅｖｅｎｔ＿ｉｄ　ｉｎ　ｔｈｅ　 events_stages_history_long　ｔａｂｌｅ．

Comment: Ｉ　ｗｉｌｌ　ｇｉｖｅ　ｍｏｒｅ　ｄｅｔａｉｌｓ　ｏｒ　ｅｘａｍｐｌｅｓ　ｎｅｘｔ　ｗｅｅｋ　ｗｈｅｎ　Ｉ　ｃａｎ　ａｃｃｅｓｓ　ｍｙ　Ｍｙｓｑｌ　ｄｂ．

Comment: @thelma May this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660763/mysql-performance-schema-not-working-properly

Comment: Server version: 5.6.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)